# How to cast properly a mock function with Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock a function and use the benefits from Typescript but I can't find the best way to do it. A bit of context, I want to test a class who use a Keycloak instance.
This is the case:

```js
import keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
import { Auth } from './auth';

jest.mock('keycloak-js');

const keycloakMock = keycloak as jest.MockedFunction<typeof keycloak>;
...
// This is what I want to use it, because TS autocomplete the methods and helps me.
keycloakMock.mockImplementation(() => ({ init: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true) }));
// but also, the TS compiler said:
```

> Type '{ init: Mock<any, any>; }' is missing the following properties
> from type 'KeycloakInstance': login, logout, register,
> accountManagement, and 11 more.ts(2740) index.d.ts(1163, 33): The
> expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

What I'm doing wrong? Because I test to set a `//@ts-ignore` and the test pass, but I don't like this solution. Also if I declare the `keycloakMock` like this:

```js
const keycloakMock = keycloak as jest.Mock;
```

Works, but without types... I tried to follow the guide from Jest about the MockedFunctions but I can't figure out how to solve it.

I'm using the following versions (if these can helps, in some way?)

```json
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "jest": "^26.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "keycloak-js": "^11.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting here a working code of mine extremely similar to your needs (hope this helps someone)

In this scenario, we depend on `'../http-base-client'` (in any case, a module that we need to mock)

1. Create `__mocks__/http-base-client` ([manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks))

```
const httpClient = {
  // mock here any method we are using from axios
  get: jest.fn(),
  post: jest.fn(),
  put: jest.fn(),
  patch: jest.fn(),
  delete: jest.fn(),
};

export default httpClient;
```

2. In the test:

```
import httpClient from '../http-base-client'; // we are to use their mocks
import { foo } from './client'; // the subject to test

const mockHttpClient = httpClient as jest.Mocked<typeof httpClient>; // ts: enable auto-complete as mock & http client

jest.mock('../http-base-client'); // load the manual mock

test('foo', async () => {
  // given
  mockHttpClient.post.mockResolvedValue({ whatever });
  
  // when
  foo();

  // then
  expect(mockHttpClient.post.mock.calls[0]).to // bla bla
  expect(mockHttpClient.post).to // bla bla
})
```